# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been having some trouble with this code. I have tried my best to stay with the book but the book seems to be wrong.

The following code should display the RSS feed for which ever radio button has been selected. You can also see the website on http://w3.cnm.edu/~bnoble/cis1210/afds/Travel/TravelDeals.html.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Travel Deals RSS Feed</title>
    <script>
        var rssRequest = false;
        function getRequestObject()
        {
            try
            {
                rssRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (requestError)
            {
                try
                {
                rssRequest = new ActiveXObject();
                }
                catch (requestError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        rssRequest = new 
                        ActiveXObject("Micorsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (requestError)
                    {
                        window.alert("I am sorry. Your browser does not support AJAX. Please upgrade your broweser and try again.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return rssRequest;
        }
        function rssUpdate()
        {
            if(!rssRequest)rssRequest = getRequestObject();
            for (var i=0; i<6; ++i)
            {
                if (document.forms[0].deals[i].checked == true)
                {
                    var rss = document.forms[0].deals[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }
            rssRequest.abort();
            rssRequest.open("get","TravelDeals.php?" + "rss" + rss, true);
            rssRequest.send(null)
            rssRequest.onreadystatechange=getRssDeals;
            //clearTimeout(recentDeals);
            //var recentDeals = setTimeout('rssUpdate()', 5000);
        }
        function getRssDeals()
        {
            if(rssRequest.readyState==4 && rssRequest.status == 200)
            {
                var deals = rssRequest.responseXML; 
                document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML = ""
                var dealsInfo=deals.getElementsByTagName("item");
                if (dealsInfo.length > 0)
                {
                    for (var i=0; i<dealsInfo.length; ++i) 
                    {
                        var curHeadline = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        var curlink = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        var curPubDate = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        var curDesc = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        var curDeal = "<a href='" + curLink + "'>" + curHeadline + "</a><br/>";
                        curDeal +=  curDesc + "<br/>";curDeal += curDesc + "<br/>";
                        document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML += curDeal;
                    }
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML = "The RSS feed appears to be broken or empty.";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="rssUpdate()">
    <h1>Travel Deals RSS</h1>
    <form method="get" action="">
        <table border="1">
            <colgroup span="1" width="125"/>
            <colgroup span="1" width="350"/>
            <tr>
                <td align="top">
                    <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://www.orbitz.com/rss/topdeals-vacationpackages.rss.xml" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Orbitz<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://www.travelocity.com/dealservice/globaltrips-shopping-svcs/deals-1.0/services/RssDealsServices?ProductType=Air&rdr=GEN&nm=My~Travelocity~Specials&typ=0&orig=ABQ&dest=PHX,LAS,LAX,NYC,LGB&id=9197I1366355523195" checked="checked" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Travelocity<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://press.hotwire.com/index.php?s=43&pagetemplate=rss" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Hotwire<br/>
                </td>
                <td id="rssFeed" valign="top></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I've seen the same question before and had posted an answer, that time there was a `td` with id `rssFeed`.

Comment: see the updated solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no element with id `rssFeed` in the page.

You can solve it by adding a `div` with id `rssFeed` in the page

```
<div id="rssFeed"></div>
```

Try this complete code, because you have unclosed element in your markup

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Travel Deals RSS Feed</title>
        <script>
            var rssRequest = false;
            function parseXML(xml){
                var parser, xmlDoc;
                if (window.DOMParser) {
                    parser = new DOMParser();
                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
                } else  {
                    // Internet Explorer
                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xmlDoc.async = false;
                    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml); 
                }
            }
            function getRequestObject()
            {
                try
                {
                    rssRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                catch (requestError)
                {
                    try
                    {
                    rssRequest = new ActiveXObject();
                    }
                    catch (requestError)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            rssRequest = new 
                            ActiveXObject("Micorsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }
                        catch (requestError)
                        {
                            window.alert("I am sorry. Your browser does not support AJAX. Please upgrade your broweser and try again.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return rssRequest;
            }
            function rssUpdate()
            {
                if(!rssRequest)rssRequest = getRequestObject();
                for (var i=0; i<6; ++i)
                {
                    if (document.forms[0].deals[i].checked == true)
                    {
                        var rss = document.forms[0].deals[i].value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                rssRequest.abort();
                rssRequest.open("get","TravelDeals.php?" + "rss" + rss, true);
                rssRequest.send(null)
                rssRequest.onreadystatechange=getRssDeals;
                //clearTimeout(recentDeals);
                //var recentDeals = setTimeout('rssUpdate()', 5000);
            }
            function getRssDeals()
            {
                if(rssRequest.readyState==4 && rssRequest.status == 200)
                {
                    var deals = parseXML(rssRequest.responseXML); document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML = ""
                    var dealsInfo=deals.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    if (dealsInfo.length > 0)
                    {
                        for (var i=0; i<dealsInfo.length; ++i) 
                        {
                            var curHeadline = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            var curlink = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            var curPubDate = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            var curDesc = dealsInfo[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                            var curDeal = "<a href='" + curLink + "'>" + curHeadline + "</a><br/>";
                            curDeal +=  curDesc + "<br/>";curDeal += curDesc + "<br/>";
                            document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML += curDeal;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        document.getElementById("rssFeed").innerHTML = "The RSS feed appears to be broken or empty.";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="rssUpdate()">
        <h1>Travel Deals RSS</h1>
        <form method="get" action="">
            <table border="1">
                <colgroup span="1" width="125"/>
                <colgroup span="1" width="350"/>
                <tr>
                    <td align="top">
                        <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://www.orbitz.com/rss/topdeals-vacationpackages.rss.xml" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Orbitz<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://www.travelocity.com/dealservice/globaltrips-shopping-svcs/deals-1.0/services/RssDealsServices?ProductType=Air&rdr=GEN&nm=My~Travelocity~Specials&typ=0&orig=ABQ&dest=PHX,LAS,LAX,NYC,LGB&id=9197I1366355523195" checked="checked" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Travelocity<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="deals" value="http://press.hotwire.com/index.php?s=43&pagetemplate=rss" onclick="rssUpdate()"/><Hotwire<br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="rssFeed"><div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found the same thing, this answer should work. I don't know how you managed to get two different sets of code.

Comment: @Zachrip Now I'm unable to trace the previous question

Comment: What do you mean by "trace" the previous question?

Comment: When you run the code with the debugger, you don't get an element with the id.  However, if you look at the source the OP is clearly making one.  See my answer above for what's really going on.

Comment: @legacybass not in the original page he posted, there is not closing tags at all

Comment: @legacybass the html code was not added by the OP somebody have edited it and added the html

Comment: Sorry, must have happened between when I saw the question and when I answered.  I did a refresh and didn't notice the change.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're missing a closing quote in your `td` element.  You have `<td id="rssFeed" valign="top></td>` when what you want is `<td id="rssFeed" valign="top"></td>`.  Fixing this should cause the element to show up.